# ssd drive not found

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have just replaced my hard drives on my laptop (MSI75)  The boot drive is okay but the tb ssd is not shown at all.  It is listed in the bios in ahci mode.
When I insert a usb stick, that also shows but when I put in a 16tb ssd external drive, that doesn't show up but the power light is on, flash cards also work okay.  All work on windows devices

Any suggestions on how to have ubuntu find the missing devices is appreciated

Comment: On the command line, watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the devices. `sudo journalctl  -b 0` will show the system startup log, and you can watch as your system discovers the hardware